# errors after adding angular material for angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

i have this errors in Google Chrome after adding "angular-material": "^1.1.12" for "angular": "1.3.15". Is it could be some version collisions?

```
Uncaught TypeError: angular.module(...).info is not a function
    at angular-aria.js:66
    at angular-aria.js:427
Uncaught TypeError: angular.module(...).info is not a function
    at angular-messages.js:294
    at angular-messages.js:829
```